# NullReferenceException on GUITexture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, nullreferenceexception, guitexture

I want to add GUITexture from script but it's error, then i try insert GUITexture (from GameObject > create other > GUI Texture) then link it to the script
but then as i try move the guitexture using pixelInset, there is error said

NullReferenceException
UnityEngine.GUITexture.get_pixelInset () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/artifacts/EditorGenerated/Graphics.cs:3254)

Here's the script

```
public GUITexture temp;

void Start () {
    temp = new GUITexture ();
    temp.pixelInset.Set (100,100,100,100);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

When you call `new GUITexture()` Unity will just make your `temp` object `null`. Then when you try to use it you get a `NullReference Exception`. Why? Because `GUITexture` inherits from `Behaviour`, it is just the way Unity is built.

#### Solution

You are already dragging your reference to the `GUItexture` via the editor, so all you need is to remove this line.

```
// Remove this line
temp = new GUITexture ();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to FunctionR's answer, it is always good to check if an object is not null before trying to do anything with it.

```
public GUITexture temp;

void Start () {
    // temp = new GUITexture (); <- Overrides the texture your assigned in the editor
    if (temp) temp.pixelInset.Set (100,100,100,100);
}
```